# Xamarin forms trouble updating Boolean with SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to create a simple Notes app with Xamarin forms. I have Entrys, a Date and then a switch to determine if the note is done or not.

When creating a new note everything works fine with inserting the data. But when I try to update a note the Switch Element always inserts as "false", the other data works with the update. I have no idea what the problem might be?

Here is the method for updating the note:

```
 public void UpdateNote(string _name, string _note, string _date, bool _done, int noteId)
    {
        _sqlconnection.Query<Notes>("UPDATE [Notes] SET Name='" + _name + "', Note='" + _note + "', Date='" + _date + "', Done='" + _done + "' WHERE [ID]='" + noteId + "'");
    }
```

And here is the click event from the Views code behind:

```
 UpdateClick.Clicked += delegate {
            _notes = new Notes();
            _notesDb = new NotesDB();
            _notes.Name = name.Text;
            _notes.Note = note.Text;
            _notes.Date = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            _notes.Done = done.IsToggled;
            _notesDb.UpdateNote(_notes.Name, _notes.Note, _notes.Date, _notes.Done, noteId);
            Navigation.PopAsync();
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no boolean type in SQLite so you have to use 0 for false and 1 for true. Also, instead of using `Query` you should use **Execute**:

```
_sqlconnection.Execute("UPDATE [Notes] SET Name='" + _name + "', Note='" + _note + "', Date='" + _date + "', Done='" + _done ? 1 : 0 + "' WHERE [ID]='" + noteId + "'");
```

From [SQLite documentation:](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

> SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

Comment: Oh! Makes much more sense now! Thanks! Although the above format doesn't seem to work for me?

Comment: I figured it out. This is what I did: ´int _doneInt = _done ? 1 : 0;´ Thanks to everyone for the help! :D`code`

Answer (score 1):

SQLite stores booleans as 0/1:

```
var _doneInt = _done : 1 : 0;
```

---

```
public void UpdateNote(string _name, string _note, string _date, bool _done, int noteId)
{
    var _doneInt = _done : 1 : 0;
    _sqlconnection.Query<Notes>("UPDATE [Notes] SET Name='" + _name + "', Note='" + _note + "', Date='" + _date + "', Done='" + _doneInt + "' WHERE [ID]='" + noteId + "'");
}
```

> #### 1.1 Boolean Datatype
>
> SQLite does not have a separate Boolean storage class. Instead, Boolean values are stored as integers 0 (false) and 1 (true).

Ref: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use update?
sent the object in to update then let sqlite.net work it out :

```
public void UpdateNote(Notes _note)
{
    _sqlconnection.Update(_note)
}
```

If you look at the update test call in [here](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/e7b8303677a3a0190cc601c091a139b60b464bc1/tests/TableChangedTest.cs) 
this is assuming that your `noteId` field has `[PrimaryKey]`

This seems to work for me:

Model:

```
    public class Notes
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, NotNull] 
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string Name { get; set; } 
        public string Note { get; set; } 
        public string Date { get; set; } 
        public bool Done { get; set; } 
    }
```

test method:

```
    public bool testForNotes(Notes n)
    {
        _sqliteConnection.CreateTable<Notes>();
        _sqliteConnection.Insert (n);
        n.Done = true;
        var i = _sqliteConnection.Update (n);
        return (i > 0);
    }
```

UNIT test

```
    public void GetNotes ()
    {
        NoteDataStore _noteDataStore = new NoteDataStore (new SqlConnection());
        var note = new Notes () {
            Name = "TestName",
            Note = "TestNote",
            Date = DateTime.Now.ToString (),
            Done = false
        };
        var show = _noteDataStore.testForNotes (note);
        Assert.IsNotNull (show);
    }
```

Comment: I have tried that and for some reason it wouldn't work for me :/

Comment: I know that the answer above solved your issue but would you be able to post your Notes model? as you wont be able to do insert, or other sqlite commands, it will have to be manual SQLite queries

Comment: Sure! Here is my model: `[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, NotNull]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public bool Done { get; set; }

        public Notes() { }`

For insert i use SQLites Insert method so I'm really confused as to why is doesn't work with update.

Comment: Do you get any errors using update in the applciation output?